# Unable to install cordova in Windows 10 with npm

Tags: cordova, npm

While running the following `npm install -g cordova`
I am getting the this error. I am not behind a proxy.

- browserify-transform-tools node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\aliasify\node_modules\browserify-transform-tools
- falafel node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\aliasify\node_modules\browserify-transform-tools\node_modules\falafel
- cordova-js node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js
- browserify node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify
- browser-pack node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\browser-pack
- crypto-browserify node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\crypto-browserify
- create-hash node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\crypto-browserify\node_modules\create-hash
- diffie-hellman node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\crypto-browserify\node_modules\diffie-hellman
- insert-module-globals node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\insert-module-globals
- lexical-scope node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\insert-module-globals\node_modules\lexical-scope
- astw node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\insert-module-globals\node_modules\lexical-scope\node_modules\astw
- module-deps node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps
- detective node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\node_modules\detective
- shasum node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\shasum
- syntax-error node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-js\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\syntax-error
- cordova-serve node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-serve
- express node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express
- send node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\cordova-serve\node_modules\express\node_modules\send
- npm node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm
- npmconf node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npmconf
- rc node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\rc
- request node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request
- tar node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\tar
- fstream node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\tar\node_modules\fstream
- xcode node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\xcode
- configstore node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\configstore
- latest-version node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version
- package-json node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json
- registry-url node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\registry-url
- rc node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\registry-url\node_modules\rc
- semver-diff node_modules\cordova\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\semver-diff
  C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm
  └── (empty)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\abbrev-3d054da1
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\abbrev-3d054da1' -> 'C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\abbrev-3d054da1' -> 'C:\Users\kamayd\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\node_modules\abbrev'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\WINDOWS\system32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Comment: I am able to install cordova in a windows 7 pc. I tried updating node and npm to the latest stable version in my windows 10 pc and no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the installation of one key component.

**Apache Ant**

To install Ant, download a zip, extract it, move the first folder in the zip to a safe place, and update your PATH to include the bin folder in that folder. For example, if you moved the Ant folder to c:/, you'd want to add this to your PATH: C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin.

[more info here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html)